# How to add rows from one dataframe to another dataframe one after another using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have two dataframe like df1

```
    time    kw
0   13:00   30
1   13:02   28
2   13:04   29
```

and df2

```
  time    kw
1   13:01   30
2   13:03   28
3   13:05   29
```

i want to add rows from one dataframe to another for end result like

```
  time    kw
1   13:00   30
2   13:01   30
3   13:02   28
4   13:03   28
5   13:04   29
6   13:05   29
```

Please help..
I concat both dataframe`result_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])`, but it just put them side by side. Secondly i tried to `append` both dataframe, but still not what i am looking for
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO. Thank you

Comment: Thank u, i just did

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([("13:00", 30), ("13:02", 28), ("13:04", 29)], columns=["time", "kw"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([("13:01", 30), ("13:03", 28), ("13:05", 29)], columns=["time", "kw"])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values("time")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) with [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
In [2362]: df1.append(df2).sort_values('time')
Out[2362]: 
    time  kw
0  13:00  30
1  13:01  30
1  13:02  28
2  13:03  28
2  13:04  29
3  13:05  29
```